# Coping with apostrophe (single quote) in username with powershell command - Get-Azureaduser

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, single-quotes

I'm cycling through a list of users and need to call `get-azureaduser` with each one.
The email address is stored in a variable `$email` and my command looks like this:

```
$user = Get-AzureAdUser -filter "mail eq '$email'"
```

This works fine for most users but not for those with an apostrophe in their name.

If there is an apostrophe it throws an error:

```
Message: Unsupported or invalid query filter clause specified for property 'mail' of resource 'User'.
```

I've tried various things for the filter parameter (e.g. surrounding in "" etc) but none of these worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to escape a single quote `'` in an [OData](https://www.odata.org/) filter is by doubling down on it, an efficient way to handle this when the value being fed to the filter *could have* single quotes in it can be with the [`.Replace` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=net-7.0). Additionally, Microsoft has a section on how to handle escaping of quotes, for queries to the **Graph API** (the same solution also applies to the old API used by the AzureAD Module). See [Escaping single quotes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters?tabs=http#escaping-single-quotes).

```bash
$email = $email.Replace("'", "''")
$user = Get-AzureAdUser -Filter "mail eq '$email'"
```

As aside, consider migrating your code to the [Microsoft.Graph Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/microsoftgraph/installation?view=graph-powershell-1.0), the AzureAD Module is deprecated and the API it's calling behind the scenes will no longer work in the future. See [**Important: Azure AD Graph Retirement and Powershell Module Deprecation**](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-entra-azure-ad-blog/important-azure-ad-graph-retirement-and-powershell-module/ba-p/3848270) for more information.

You can use [`Get-MgUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.users/get-mguser?view=graph-powershell-1.0) as a replacement in this case, the code would look pretty similar:

```bash
$email = $email.Replace("'", "''")
$user = Get-MgUser -Filter "mail eq '$email'"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using escaped double quotes instead of single quotes around `$email`, like so:

```
Get-AzureAdUser -Filter "mail eq `"$email`""
```