# Getting all devices registered to given a user with powershell

Tags: powershell, scripting, azure-active-directory

When I run the following it will return with the correct Device ID but the Device Name is blank. What am I doing wrong?

```
Connect-AzureAD 

$user = Get-AzureADUser -Filter "userPrincipalName eq 'myuser@mydomain.com'"
$userObjectId = $user.ObjectId

$assignedDevices = Get-AzureADUserRegisteredDevice -ObjectId $userObjectId

foreach ($device in $assignedDevices) {
    Write-Host "Device Name: $($device.DeviceName)"
    Write-Host "Device ID: $($device.DeviceId)"
    Write-Host "-----------------------"
}

Disconnect-AzureAD
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the property is called `DisplayName` not `DeviceName`:

```
Connect-AzureAD 

$user = Get-AzureADUser -Filter "userPrincipalName eq 'myuser@mydomain.com'"
$userObjectId = $user.ObjectId

$assignedDevices = Get-AzureADUserRegisteredDevice -ObjectId $userObjectId

foreach ($device in $assignedDevices) {
    Write-Host "Device Name: $($device.DisplayName)"
    Write-Host "Device ID: $($device.DeviceId)"
    Write-Host "-----------------------"
}

Disconnect-AzureAD
```

Comment: That was the answer thank you. However the -eq does not work the original syntax there was correct.

Comment: Ah glad it worked, sorry I'll remove the syntax part, I thought it would match filters in Where-Object etc.

Comment: `Get-AzureADUser` uses [OData syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/filter-query-parameter) with `-Filter`. Also, it looks like the `AzureAD` module is _deprecated_; however, the `Get-MgUser` cmdlet from the successor `Microsoft.Graph` module uses the same syntax - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77320625/45375).